# Минимальный парсер псевдоязыка программирования

Tags: c#, winforms, синтаксический-анализ

Для университетского проекта (симуляция ОС) нужно сделать некое подобие ЯП с минимальным синтаксисом. То есть объявление переменных, арифметические операции, вывод...

Вопрос таков: каким образом будет лучше сделать парсинг строки с командой? Через Regex или искать команды в строке методами String? Интересует не столько скорость работы, сколько удобство и аккуратность реализации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы написать минимальный язык программирования, вам придётся писать парсер. Вы должны решить **заранее**, будут ли в вашем языке программирования вложенные структуры, например, будет ли `while`, в который может быть вложена произвольная команда или набор команд.

Если ваш язык простой, вы можете разбирать его как угодно — вручную, регулярками, как вам нравится.

Но если вдруг ваш язык рекурсивный — забудьте все эти игрушки, вам придётся писать настоящий, честный парсер. Это не получится слёту, просто так: вам придётся читать книги.

Для написания простого recursive descent-парсера (это парсер языка типа Паскаля) стоит почитать Н. Вирта «[Алгоритмы + структуры данных = программы](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs)».

Если у вас ещё более сложная грамматика (что вряд ли), вам придётся засесть за классическую «книгу с драконом». Учтите, что это сделает вас специалистом по парсерам, что, возможно, не так уж плохо для будущей специальности.

---

Это, кстати, не вся работа: кроме front-end'а (то есть парсера), вам придётся написать и back-end (генератор машинных кодов). Я бы посоветовал выбрать один из существующих бинарных форматов, и воспользоваться стандартным back-end'ом (например, Clang или .NET CIL). Для этого, конечно, вам придётся быть бинарно совместимыми с одной из существующих платформ. А если вы уж бинарно совместимы, почему тогда не взять связку Pure C/gcc?

Comment: Ну, учитывая то, что это только симуляция, писать это подобие я планирую на c#, т.к. проще сделать интерфейс, то весь бекенд будет на костылях, скорее всего. Что касается синтаксиса - я не планирую делать циклы, максимум - if и какой-то goto, но это еще не точно. 
Попробую регулярками, скорее всего. Спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @thatside: Тогда я посоветовал бы делать не компилятор, а интерпретатор. Таким образом вы сэкономите на back end'е.

Comment: Порылся, побродил по инету и увидел, что можно использовать Javascript в C#. Это вариант достаточно удобный, скорее всего, буду писать либо просто на нем, но без использования функций, циклов, и т.д., либо все же сделаю некий парсер, чтобы приводить собственные команды к командам JS.